# Operations on transfer function model

Tags: functions, control-systems

Suppose I have a transfer function defined via `TransferFunctionModel`, e.g. `tf == TransferFunctionModel[{{1/s}}, s]`. How can I perform operations on `tf`, e.g. multiplication. As an example, I may want to use it as follows `RootLocusPlot[k tf, {k, 0, 10}]` which does not work.

Is there a way to extract a transfer function model such that it can be modified, e.g. similar to the way `Normal` works for `StateSpaceModel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Just use the tf, with no `k` multiplied in the call to RootLocusPlot.

The `k` goes to the `tf` it self. Like this

```
sys = TransferFunctionModel[k*(s^2 + 2 s + 4)/(s (s + 4)(s + 6)(s^2 + 1.4 s + 1)), s];
RootLocusPlot[sys, {k, 0, 100}, 
    ImageSize -> 300, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Dashed, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> Is there a way to extract a transfer function model such that it can
>   be modified, e.g. similar to the way Normal works for StateSpaceModel

I am not sure what you mean. the tf, is the polynomial ratio in `s` you had at the start, so you have this allready. You can always go  `First@tf` to get it again.

Comment: Is it always the case that `tf == TransferFunctionModel[tf[[1, 1]]/tf[[1, 2]], s]`?

Comment: Yes. transfer function, before passing it to Mathematica's `TransferFunctionModel`, is just ratio of 2 polynomials, like in the textbooks.  So this is `tf= k * N(s)/D(s)`, where `N(s)` is the numerator poly, and `D(s)` is the denominator poly.  Now, you just do  `fancyTf=TransferFunctionModel[tf]` only to be able to use `fancyTf` as a Mathematica transfer model. Since mathematica only knows it inside this wrapper. (ps. you should use `==` in the above, it is just `=`, a normal assignment)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the mathematica model connections.  For the full list see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ModelConnections.html

For example using the function SystemsModelSeriesConnect:

```
tf = TransferFunctionModel[{{1/s}}, s];

SystemsModelSeriesConnect[TransferFunctionModel[k, s], tf]
```

Output is the gain, k multiplied  by the original transfer function.  You can do more complex multiplications and parallel combinations, feedback arrangements, etc. with the various connections.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
tf = TransferFunctionModel[{{1/s}}, s]
ClearAttributes[Times, Protected];
Times[k_, TransferFunctionModel[m_, s_]] := 
    TransferFunctionModel[k m, s]
SetAttributes[Times, Protected];
```

But you would have to modify a lot of operations.

Comment: Not feasible, IMO, because fundamental arithmetic operations are subject to special optimizations and can fail to apply (or lose completely) their user-defined rules at any moment. It would be better to make this definition on `TransferFunctionModel` than `Times`.

Comment: I tried that but got some complaints about a tag being nested too deep...